# Django runserver permanent

Tags: django, shell

How can I make the development server from django running permanent? So that it does't stop when I quit the shell.

Thanks

Comment: I do hope you are not asking this for use on a production server. It will lead you to only evil if you are.

Comment: You're supposed to only have the shell open when you're developing.  This is NOT meant for production!

Comment: And for beta testers?

Answer (score 93):

another easy way to do this is to run:

```
[user@host]$screen
[user@host]$python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

Now press `Ctrl+A` and then press `d` to exit from this screen.

This creates the server in a screen and then detaches it.  This way you can simply go back in and type:

```
[user@host]$screen -r
```

and you can take control of the server again and see whats going on.

You can also [detach from the screen immediately](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html#toc-Invoking-Screen-1):

```sh
screen -d -m python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

Comment: Can one logout and get back to the screen though?

Comment: @AdamNelson Yes, if you don't explicitly terminate a screen session it will keep running even past a logout.

Comment: One problem with this solution is that running the server launches the server console and one cannot provide commands to the terminal, hence cannot run the screen -d method

Comment: cannot type `screen -d` here as control is retained by the launching of the server here. Use `Ctrl+A` and then press `d` again to quit from this screen. You can then logout from your server too. When needed, you log back in to your server and type `screen -r` to return to the screen that you had started a while ago

Comment: can we run multiple server on a screen?

Answer (score 67):

If you are on Linux/Unix use the "nohup" command.

```
nohup python3 manage.py runserver &
```

Then to get it back, use the fg command:

```
fg
```

Thanks to: Xiong Chiamiov

Comment: This won't allow you to exit the shell as a job will be running.  Right?

Comment: @Adam N. You will be able to exit the shell, the nohup is for "no hangup", it will keep running the job after you leave the shell.

Comment: @MikeN: if you leave the shell, I believe there is no way to return to the job later in the future, as fg only work for the current shell.

Comment: Drat.  Im doing that, but django crashes with "inappropriate ioctl for device"  thoughts?

Comment: create a logfile too as ```nohup python3 manage.py runserver 192.xxx.xx.xx:8000 > /home/xxxx/xxxx/nohup_xxxx.out &```

Answer (score 32):

Like Travis says-- use screen. If you don't already have it installed, go get it:

```
sudo apt-get install screen
screen
```

Hit enter. Now it's like you're in a different terminal window.

Start you server with:

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

Now you're running the server, and you'd like to get back to your first screen while letting the django app continue running. Screen has a nice feature built-in for that. To get back to your main terminal type:

```
ctrl+a d
```

From there, you can get back to the django screen by typing:

```
screen -r
```

If you have multiple screens open you can reach the correct one by it's 4-5 digit ID number:

```
screen -r 1333
```

And the man pages are pretty good:

```
man screen
```

Comment: I'm highly interested in your solution. Since I'm using CentOS, I had to use `pipl install screen`. Installation was a success but then I type `screen` and get -bash: screen: command not found. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: @dmitrymar even though you may have successfully installed screen, it seems not to be in your PATH. You'll want to figure out where pipl installed it, and make sure that the directory that it was installed into is in the PATH. Check `echo $PATH` to see what the current path is. And `which screen` to verify that your shell sees it somewhere in the path.

Answer (score 8):

```
on Ubuntu run:>./manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000 > /dev/null 2>&1 &

>exit
```

Comment: +1 this is simple and I can confirm it works on centos as well (and can't think of any good reason it'd be platform-specific, given that you're on a unix system with bash)

Answer (score 3):

create a file with this, example */tmp/screendjango*:

```
screen python manage.py runserver
```

and then you put:

```
screen -dmS django -c /tmp/screendjango
```

for attach the sessión you put

```
screen -d -r django.
```

Comment: I think that's the most complicated way to use screen, ever.

Answer (score 2):

For windows you can use following command

```html
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

For ubuntu/linux use

```html
nohup python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000 &
```

for go back from nohup command use fg command

```html
fg
```

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, run

```
pythonw.exe manage.py runserver
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm just about to do this myself.  The scenario is that I'm rapid prototyping for a client and they need to see what things look like.  There will never be more than 2-3 people on this at a time, but I don't want to set up Apache or stay logged in.

```
sudo ./manage.py runserver 192.168.1.94:80 [run this on port 80 so a normal business user can see it]
ctrl+z [to suspend the job (same thing as appending & to the above command but then I don't need to deal with entering the sudo password on the command line)]
bg %1 [puts the job in the background]
jobs [just to see what's going on]
exit [exit the session]
```