# How to run django development server at startup?

Tags: python, django

I added following command to Sessions -> Startup program but it didn't work. I'm using Ubuntu.

```
sudo -u www-data python manage.py 192.168.1.2:8001
```

192.168.1.2 is the ip address on ath0. Is it still not available for binding at the stage when this command is executed?

What I currently do is add another cronjob to restart the development server if it's not running every 5 minutes? Is it a better way to run it at startup?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hopefully you're not trying to run the server in a production environment (according to the [django docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#runserver)).  Take a look instead at [apache with mod_wsgi](http://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/django_apache_and_mod_wsgi).

If you are just running for local development, there is no need to run as the www-data user. You might want to look into the [@reboot directive for cron](http://jeremy.zawodny.com/blog/archives/001021.html), and just run the server as your user.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1188542/django-runserver-permanent/1188577#1188577) for details on runserver.

Comment: Yes, it's for local development only. I just dont want to start the development server on every reboot.

Comment: Another thing you could do (although not the best solution), is to put the start command (likely changing directory first) in your ~/.bashrc file, so it is run whenever you log in.

Comment: You can still use mod_wsgi for local development. See 'http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2008/12/using-modwsgi-when-developing-django.html'.

Answer (score 3):

Mmmm... shouldn't it be?

> sudo -u www-data python manage.py **runserver** 192.168.1.2:8001

Answer (score 1):

If you want the dev server to always run, you're probably better off setting up a real server on your local machine. It doesn't have to be something fat or big. I use [cherokee](http://www.cherokee-project.com/doc/cookbook_django.html) server. Another options is [lighttpd](http://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/ServerArrangements#lighttpd)