# How to run Django server in daemon mode?

Tags: django

I want to run Django development server in Daemon mode so that when I quit the shell the server still would be running. How can I do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Django runserver permanent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1188542/django-runserver-permanent)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you on Linux? Two options:

1. Use `screen` http://linux.die.net/man/1/screen
2. Start the Django server with `nohup` http://linux.die.net/man/1/nohup

Answer (score 5):

In addition to what @Bernhard said, If you plan to use this for a production environment you should run django under apache with mod_wsgi:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/

Comment: Thank you Variant! Yes, I am planning to move on production environment later so it would be helpful for me.