# How to execute mulitple commands in single line linux (openshift / docker )

Tags: django, linux, docker, celery, openshift

I'm looking for a way to run django server and celery in single line. The services (django and celery) are deployed in openshift as two separate pods with same image and currently i'm running django service (pod) using `python manage.py runserver` and celery (pod) using `celery -A myapp worker --loglevel=info --concurrency=8`

instead of running separate pods for each, i want to execute the runserver command and celery worker command together. How to do that.

I know **&& ; ||** is used for such scenarios. but those doesn't work.

for example :

```
cd ./app && python manage.py runserver  #this works

cd ./app && python manage.py runserver && celery -A myapp worker --loglevel=info --concurrency=8
#this will cd to app, execute runserver command. but celery command doesn't get executed.
```

Comment: Running two separate Deployments for this (overriding the `command:` in the Celery worker) is the standard pattern.  There are some huge hidden complexities to trying to run two processes in one container, including figuring out what to restart if only one of the components fails.  Separate Deployments also will let you scale the two components separately, so you can have 3 application containers feeding 20 background workers if that fits your load pattern.

Comment: yes that's correct. but i wanted to run them together because, when celery executes it creates some media files and that cannot be accessed by nginx media route. if i can run both django and celery together, the files will be created at a location which is having a nginx reverse proxy

Comment: @DavidMaze is there any other way to do what i have mentioned in above comment ? since celery does not expose a service, i'm unbale to point media to celery pod

Comment: You need to run django's server in daemon mode. Since you start the django server first, it does not execute the next task i.e. Celery. Have a look at this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/14438536/9223271

Comment: @Mehak answer below by sbabti is allowing to run multiple commands together. But running django and celery in single pod isn't adviced as mentioned by David in above comments. So i wanted to know if there is any way i can point nginx to celery pod for /media requests? Since running celery doesn't expose a service i cannot do it the normal way using a proxy pass

Comment: figured out a way to do that. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create a bash file and add in it the two commands like this :

```
python manage.py runserver &
celery -A myapp worker --loglevel=info --concurrency=8
```

make it executable with "chmod +x"

and run it in your docker container with
bash my_file.sh

Comment: yes this works to run multiple commands. but first command cd ./app has no impact...manage.py and celery command will work only inside apps directory. so how to cd to app directory and execute rest of the commands there ?

Comment: you have to add this line in your dockerfile (WORKDIR your_path) like this: 
WORKDIR /app   
before the CMD line

Comment: WORKDIR is set to the directory before app. that cannot be changed in my scenario. The reason i have asked for running multiple commands is mentioned in the comments section of the question. if you have any idea or experience with such scenario, please share your inputs

Answer (score 0):

The && joins two commands, and means the following command will run AFTER THE FIRST HAS FINISHED, and depending on it's exit code.

It's a logical and -- so, if the first command returns false, the second doesn't run (since the logical and is already known to evaluate as false).

Try this:

cd /path; ( python manage.py runserver &); ( celery -A myapp worker --loglevel=info --concurrency=8 &);

The final & puts celery in the background as well.  Remove it if you want celery in the foreground.  As noted above, this is not a "container native" design - if you have one process per container the rest of the management becomes significantly more straightforward.  It's commonly worthwhile to figure out the rest of the adjustments needed (e.g. an emptyDir{} can be used to share files between containers within the pod) and simplify deployment sooner rather than later.